# I'm getting a unicode error that prevents my code from running

Tags: r

I think my problem is Turkish character error in R.

Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/sample/OneDrive -  Sa?l?k �r/Belgeler":The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect inside batch

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you could try check the encoding using

```
enc <- Encoding(path)
```

and then convert it to UTF-8

```
enc.path <- iconv(path, enc, "UTF-8")
```

and then use enc.path as the path

Seriously, I don know if this works, but you could try it (it's free!)

Comment: Honestly not working. The unicode string is just like in global "options -> default working directory".

Comment: The you should change the directory where your files are (for this project) in a path without encoded characters like (C:/Belgeler/). Then `setwd("C:/Belgeler/")` and `rstudioapi::filesPaneNavigate(getwd())`...